# How to find the duplicate elements without override equals

Tags: java, duplicates, set, treeset

I have a list of class A

```
public class A {
    String port;
    String ip;
    String name;
    Obeject ...others;
}
```

In this list, I want to find the duplicate elements which share the same ip and port.

1. Overriding equals() to compare ip and port and using hashSet maybe a method to solve this. But I think equals() should not be override because there are other field in this class, it may confuse the logic.
2. Using TreeSet and implement Comparator is another way. But ip and ports are hard to compare which is greater since we have ipv6, ipv4, ip range, port range etc. In compare(), if only return 0 when ip and port equal and return 1 if they are not equal will cause a logical error. Because TreeSet is implemented by red-black tree.
3. A subclass called AHelper with overriding equals() may work. But I think it is stupid.

Is there any other way to solve this question?  ~~~Many thanks.

Comment: Option 2 looks good to me, and there will be no avoiding comparing IPs and ports as far as I know.

Comment: Overriding `equals` to simply compare two properties is not a good choice - I'd start with a utility method which takes to instances of `A` and compares their properties and returns `true` or `false`. I'd even consider making a `Equatable` interface which could provider you more flexibility when it comes to comparing two objects, so you can easily change the way in which the comparison is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new class `IpAndPort` that includes just the `ip` and `port` fields, and override `equals()` on that class so that it compares the two fields.  Define a `Map` whose key is `IpAndPort`, and whose value is either `A` or `List<A>`, depending on your needs.  Go through the `List<A>`, and for each element, create the `IpAndPort`.  Now add this to the map where the `IpAndPort` is the key, and either (1) add the `A` to the map as a value; or (2) collect all the `A`'s in the map for each key in a `List<A>`.  Or something else (you could make it a `Map<IpAndPort, Integer>` and just count the number of values for each IP/Port key).

You could also eliminate a little redundancy by making the `IpAndPort` object an instance variable in `A`, replacing the `ip` and `port` variables.

Comment: Method 3 sounded to me like defining a subclass of `A`, while this solution defines a separate class to hold just the key info.

Answer (score 0):

I think Option 2 is the best bet as the job of Comparator is something of an external factor which introduces ordering.Since you mentioned IPs are hard to comnpare,why not have IPv4 and IPv6 as separate attributes.What kind of data gets populated in the object has to be controlled.Its like saying how do I compare my full name with my nick name.I think the main problem is there is no universal rule of comparision.What you compare and how you compare is something you will have to come up with as a designer/developer

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can use Predicate to filter elements in List :

```
ArrayList<A> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<A> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Stream<A> stream = list1.stream();
        for (A a2 : list2) {
            stream.filter(a1 -> a1.getIp().equals(a2.getIp()) && a1.getPort().equals(a2.getPort()));
        }
```

`list1` will retain only objects `A` whose `ip` and `port` is the same as in `list2`.

Comment: Is it O(n2)? I think it's no different from double loop.